# React Route does not work - Single page app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a single page app with route but it is not working.
It only works when i type the url manually, but if i click it doesnt redirect to the page.

i'm using an sidemenu.js to render the list and in the app.js to render the content.

Here it is:

```
 app.js


function App() {



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HashRouter>
        <BrowserRouter>
<Switch>

<Route exact path="/Home">
  <Home />
</Route>



<Route  exact path="/Consultas"> 
  <Consultas />
</Route>



<Route  path="/diagnosticos"  exact  component={<Diagnosticos/>}/>



<Route  path="/Noticias" component={Noticias}/>



<Route  path="/Configs" component={Configuracoes}/>
</Switch>


    
    </BrowserRouter>
</HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


sidemenu.js

function SideMenu() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div id="sideMenu">
      <img src={require('./HwBC.png')} alt="" />
      <hr />
      <h1>menu</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>

      <ul>
        <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink exact to="/consultas">Consultas</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/diagnosticos">Diagnostiocos</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/noticias">Noticias</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/configs">Configuracoes</NavLink></li>
      </ul>

      </BrowserRouter>

      </div>  

      </HashRouter>
  )
};

export default SideMenu;
```

And i have already other solutions in some post and it havent worked yet.

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? There were some breaking changes between v5 and v6.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the SideMenu component? Where it is mounted

Comment: react-router-dom is 5.3.0. And they are like this, im not calling specificly. Before everything was in sidemenu together but it wasnt working as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are rendering the routes and the links to them into two separate routing contexts. Only a single routing context is necessary for the ***entire*** React application.

Also, you likely don't need both a `HashRouter` ***and*** a `BrowserRouter`. Pick the one the suits your app's needs.

## Solution

Render all the routes and links into a single routing context. Lift the `HashRouter`/`BrowserRouter` up the ReactTree such that only a single router is wrapping both the `App` rendering the routes and the `SideMenu` components.

Example:

index.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <SideMenu />
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/Consultas"> 
          <Consultas />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/diagnosticos" component={Diagnosticos} />
        <Route path="/Noticias" component={Noticias} />
        <Route path="/Configs" component={Configuracoes}/ >
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SideMenu

```
function SideMenu() {
  return (
    <div id="sideMenu">
      <img src={require('./HwBC.png')} alt="" />
      <hr />
      <h1>menu</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/consultas">Consultas</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/diagnosticos">Diagnostiocos</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/noticias">Noticias</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/configs">Configuracoes</NavLink></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
};

export default SideMenu;
```